# Sitecore Forms script are not loading intermittenly

Tags: sitecore-forms

We have Sitecore forms added in one of page and we have referenced the RenderFormsScript method. Intermittently script are not loaded in to our pages. Is there way to find the root cause?

Comment: Try to disable the cache for the the form itself and its parent component and see what happens

Comment: Could you please move all your script to Themes

Answer (score 0):

Try this first that, the `@Html.RenderFormScripts()` is presented before the end of the body tag and if you inspect the element then you will be able to see the Sitecore-related JS reference.

If still, you are getting the issues then you need to check if other scripts added on the page are creating the issue? If they exist then you need to remove those to verify that they are creating the issue.

Your Layout or the page should look like this.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>
   <head>
   @Html.RenderFormStyles()
   
    . . . . . . .
   </head>
   <body>
      . . . . . 
      @Html.RenderFormScripts()
   </body>
</html>
```